# Deleting control points in ArcGIS Georeferencing?

Tags: georeferencing, arcgis-10.2

I'm trying to georeference a raster in ArcMap 10.2 using a rivers vector (polyline) feature class. I started by shifting and rotating the raster. However when deleting a control point to reduce my RMS, both shift and rotation are "being automatically" canceled and I need to shift and rotate the raster back again.

It only occurs in "Auto Adjust" mode.;

Does somebody have a clue about the origin of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for that problem, but after I removed the Raster from my .mxd and reloaded it - the problem was fixed.

Now I can delete control points without it messing my shift and rotation of the raster.